# Hypergeometric distribution - How do I evaluate this expected value?

Tags: probability

Suppose to have a random variable $X$ which follows an hypergeometric distribution (see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution) as reference).

Let $P(X = k) = p_k$ and $g(X, K) = \max(0, aX + b(K+1))$.

I would like to evaluate the expected value of $g(X, K)$:

$$\mathbb{E}[g(X, K)] = \sum_k g(k,K)p_k$$

Some suggestion?

Comment: What makes you think the obvious summation can be simplified?

Comment: I hope that it can be simplified and for this reason I asked it here :D

Comment: "Abandon all hope, ye who enter here"... :-)

Comment: Ok. So, for general pdf and general $g(X)$, are there some techniques  to obtain upper and lower bound for $\mathbb{E}[g(X)]$?

Comment: My previous comment answers this.